# Display content of database in a form in struts2

Tags: struts2

Display content of database in a form with textfields in struts2.
Here is a senario. It's just an example.There is a jsp page (abc.jsp) which shows list of employees. This page contains  a button (Add employee), when user clicks this button an action abcAction is called which opens xyz.jsp asking user to fill necessary information like emp_ID, emp_name, etc. On sucess abc.jsp page is opened showing the entered information on a table. Along with this informtaion an"edit" button is appeared on the same page(abc.jsp). Now how to display xyz.jsp page when user cicks edit button along with the necessary fields entered by the user based on emp_ID.

Comment: Are you serious? You expect someone to write whole code for you. Share with us what have you tried so far. All the problems you mentioned are very basic struts2 operations. [Here is a simple tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-struts2-hibernate-example-eclipse/) showing how to implement the basic CRUD operations

Comment: No, i have not asking for the whole code.I was acutally asking for some logic or some code snippets which could slove the above  problem..

Comment: The tutorial which I mentioned was very helpful to me. I hope it works for you too

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, but i didn't find solution to my problem..:(

Comment: Which part of your problem are you stuck? Share your code and ask specific problems. [Take a look here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Soory @anu I couldn't explain my problem clearly..:(

Comment: What i actually want was to populate all the database content to an action class so that i could show those values on a form..

Comment: ok take a look at [this](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-crud-example-1.html) tutorial. Also, if you could tell what kind of data or object you want to load and edit, I would help you forward. Is it a list of objects or a single object or string/integer values?

Comment: Thanks @anu this tutorial helped me alot..I wanted to populate list of objects on my action class, n i thing i did that with the help of above tutorial..

Comment: Great then. Happy coding